# Does an enemy have to make the save against the Spirit Guardians spell if the caster moves within 15 feet of the enemy?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement, saving-throw, area-of-effect

Does the *Spirit Guardians* spell trigger its saving throw if you, as the caster, close the 15-ft. gap?
Or only when the enemy uses its movement to come into the spell's radius? *Spirit Guardians* says:

> when the creature enters the area for the first time on a turn or starts its turn there, it must make a Wisdom saving throw.

For instance, say I'm 30 feet away, and I use 15 feet of movement to bring myself within range of the monster to put it within the spell's range.
Does that initiate the "when the creature enters the area for the first time on a turn" trigger for the spell's saving throw?
Or would the creature have to close that gap itself?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Please review the linked question and see if it addresses your question; if not, please edit your question to clarify how it is distinct/not the same as that question.

Comment: Related (not a duplicate, since it's about a different spell): [Is the Moonbeam spell amazing, or are we doing it wrong?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/53120/33569)

Comment: @V2Blast The language of *moonbeam* is exactly the same. It is a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @RobertPainVanZant [please don't answer in comments](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/14878).